# Uniform Convergence of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Show that for each $r> 0$, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2 -z}$ converges uniformly on the set $E_r = \{z: |z| \leq r, z\neq k^2$ for $k = 0,1,2,3, ...\}$.

I tried to use the Weierstrass M-test but I get stuck in choosing my M-value. 
$|\frac{1}{k^2-z}| = \frac{1}{k^2 - |z|} \leq \frac{1}{k^2 - r}$.  At this point I do not know what to compare this series to.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f_k(z):=1/(k^2-z)$. Then for $k\gt \sqrt r$, and $z\in E_r$, $|f_k(z)|\leqslant 1/(k^2-r)$, hence for these $k$, $\sup_{z\in E_r}|f_k(z)|\leqslant 1/(k^2-r)$.
The series $\sum_{k\gt\sqrt r}1/(k^2-r)$ is convergent because so is the series $\sum_{k\geqslant 1}k^{-2}$.